# fbchat Python library instillation error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm sorry for the long read, and thank you in advance. I've posted all my outputs from CMD, but I paraphrase the main error at the end.

I'm trying to install the python library fbchat for a virtual assistant program that I am creating, however, I am having some very strange issues trying to pip install this on my Windows 10 pc.

Below is the output of my command prompt:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\lukec>pip install fbchat
Requirement already satisfied: fbchat in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\fbchat-0.5.0-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from fbchat)
Collecting lxml (from fbchat)
  Using cached lxml-3.7.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.5.1-py2.7.egg (from fbchat)
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml ... error
  Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\lukec\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-1ul2r3\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\lukec\appdata\local\temp\tmpmna48rpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  Building lxml version 3.7.1.
  Building without Cython.
  ERROR: 'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.

  ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

  Using build configuration of libxslt
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
  copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
  copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
  copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
  copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
  copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
  copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
  copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
  copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
  copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
  copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml
  C:\Users\lukec\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Isrc\lxml\includes -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcsrc\lxml\lxml.etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.obj -w
  cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
  lxml.etree.c
  src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
  Compile failed: command 'C:\\Users\\lukec\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  creating users
  creating users\lukec
  creating users\lukec\appdata
  creating users\lukec\appdata\local
  creating users\lukec\appdata\local\temp
  C:\Users\lukec\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/libxml2 /Tcc:\users\lukec\appdata\local\temp\xmlXPathInitzjpakr.c /Fousers\lukec\appdata\local\temp\xmlXPathInitzjpakr.obj
  xmlXPathInitzjpakr.c
  c:\users\lukec\appdata\local\temp\xmlXPathInitzjpakr.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
  *********************************************************************************
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
  *********************************************************************************
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\lukec\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\lukec\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-1ul2r3\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\lukec\appdata\local\temp\pip-cdhadi-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Building lxml version 3.7.1.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: 'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.

    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
    copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
    copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
    copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
    copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
    copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
    copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
    copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
    copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
    copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\html
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml
    copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml
    C:\Users\lukec\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Isrc\lxml\includes -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcsrc\lxml\lxml.etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.obj -w
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
    lxml.etree.c
    src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
    Compile failed: command 'C:\\Users\\lukec\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    C:\Users\lukec\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/libxml2 /Tcc:\users\lukec\appdata\local\temp\xmlXPathInitnuupun.c /Fousers\lukec\appdata\local\temp\xmlXPathInitnuupun.obj
    xmlXPathInitnuupun.c
    c:\users\lukec\appdata\local\temp\xmlXPathInitnuupun.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\lukec\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\lukec\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-1ul2r3\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\lukec\appdata\local\temp\pip-cdhadi-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\lukec\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-1ul2r3\lxml\
```

At the end, it says I'm getting error code one, and right before that, it says "        Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?"

```
*********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
*********************************************************************************
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\lukec\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\lukec\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-1ul2r3\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\lukec\appdata\local\temp\pip-cdhadi-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\lukec\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-1ul2r3\lxml\
```

I've tried looking at how to install libxml2 on windows 10 but with no luck. When I download the latest version from [here](http://xmlsoft.org/downloads.html), I have trouble installing the module with python. (I unzip the file, go into it, and locate a setup.py, but get the error below:)

```
C:\Users\lukec\Downloads\libxml2-2.9.4\libxml2-2.9.4\python>python setup.py install
failed to find headers for libxml2: update includes_dir
```

Any ideas? I would really appreciate any help, I've made this a project to do over school break and would like to have all functionality done before I go back! I've found another slack page a while back but can't seem to find it again, but it's instructions were a little to vague for me. :(

Thank you again and I hope for any suggestions on what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just had the same issue - what I did is the following:

-- Downloaded libxml and lxml from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

-- Install it via "pip install Filename.whl"

--  Run pip install fbchat

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! The win32 versions worked and fbchat has installed now.